# Use MDC to provide origin authentication for public key encryption?

Tags: encryption, public-key, authentication, keys, authenticated-encryption

Why can't we use an MDC (*“Manipulation Detection Code*”, as also handled in [this Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9395/12164)) to provide origin authentication when using public-key encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Public key encryption uses a public key of the receiver; anybody can encrypt. So origin authentication would only work if you'd also have a shared secret key (in which case the whole public key encryption becomes kind of useless) or a private key (in which case you'd probably use a signature or an authenticated key agreement protocol).