# CBC-Mode Infinite Garble Extension

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, modes-of-operation

A variation of the CBC mode is the [Inﬁnite Garble Extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008010212/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ige/ige-spec.pdf#page=16).

I can neither find a block diagram of it, nor the formulas for encryption and decryption. I would really like to learn more about it but there is not much online information available which helps.

What is the main difference between "normal" *CBC* and the *CBC Inﬁnite Garble Extension* if I decrypt blocks ?

Comment: The question looks a bit silly now that I have added a link to the paper with the equations; dunno how to best fix this.

Comment: @fgrieu Just leave it be? Seems fine with me. EDIT But the link doesn't work for me. ADDITIONAL EDIT : now it does.

Comment: there is some documentation/information in www.links.org/files/openssl-ige.pdf

Comment: the link in the question works via the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20170329121526/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ige/ige-spec.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The infinite garble extension makes sure that if a ciphertext block is changed that this block *and each block after it* doesn't decrypt correctly. The way that additional plaintext is affected when the ciphertext is changed is called *error propagation*. Error propagation over large parts of the plaintext is mainly interesting if you want to combine it with some MDC: Manipulation Detection Code. Then the MDC can be used to verify integrity of the plaintext.

Nowadays we simply encrypt-and-authenticate using CBC + MAC or an authenticated cipher. Error propagation is of little use if you're already verified the ciphertext for integrity and authenticity. Hence you won't find too many mentions of these (computationally intensive) modes of operation; they are mainly used for niche problems where using an authentication tag isn't the right solution.

---

With most other modes there is a limited amount of error propagation. With CBC and CBF only the same plaintext block and the next plaintext block will not be the original plaintext. With CTR mode only the modified bits are affected; there is no error propagation.

---

There is also Bi-IGE which does the same, but in two directions: every plaintext block will be changed even if just one bit of ciphertext is changed. So each bit of plaintext is flipped with a 50% possibility (and at least 1 bit with 100% certainty, but that's inconsequential).

---

More information [can be found in my question and the resulting answer about MDC / IGE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/practical-uses-of-manipulation-detection-code-mdc-and-ige).

Comment: thanks, thats really interessting. 
But is there a difference between CBC IGE and the CFB Mode ?
If i understood that correctly in the CFB Mode if a ciphertext block is changed that this block and each block after it doesn't encrypt also correctly.

Comment: Where is the difference here ?

Comment: Actually, with CBC and CFB mode, if you modify a ciphertext block, the decryption of the modified ciphertext has two blocks "wrong"; the rest of the blocks are decrypted correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "doesn't decrypt correctly" in the first paragraph?

Comment: A "manipulation detection code" isn't a MAC?

Comment: @Melab I finally found a reference [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=81qrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA327&lpg=PA327&dq=Manipulation+Detection+Code&source=bl&ots=WYQSJ2n2XR&sig=yHHIi61YMAZAWZX1GOX6G82s8oU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG2_byhp7ZAhXDC-wKHbOtBZc4ChDoAQhkMAk#v=onepage&q=Manipulation%20Detection%20Code&f=false). It explicitly mentions that an MDC is generated by "non-cryptographic means". I presume that for IGE this could be a constant value; but note that there are attacks on CBC / CFB mode operation when MDC's are used. Which is probably why they have been forgotten for anything *but* IGE.

Comment: Google Books is refusing to show me those pages.

Comment: Hmm, OK, don't know what I can do about that; maybe you need to have an account and be logged in.